# My disk at half size after formatting

Tags: linux, windows, disk-space, mbr, gpt

I'm a long time linux user, I'm also a Windows user, after formatting my brand new USB dongle I get ~30Gb from the partition table available to create a new partition where the nominal capacity of the USB pen i 64Gb.

I tried with the Windows 8 utility `diskpart` using both `convert gpt` and `convert mbr`, I used `diskmgmt.msc` too, I also tried `fdisk`, `cfdisk`, `gdisk` and `gparted` on linux, the result is always the same with ~30Gb free and I can't see any figure bigger than that .

What just happened to my disk ? I just tried to format my USB to NTFS under Windows and from there I got this and I have no idea about how to fix this nor from where the problem is being originated .

Comment: How reputable is this flash drive? It sounds a bit fishy to me.

Comment: @digitxp it's a brand that starts with _V_ and ends with _tim_, it's actually a really popular brand in the memory market .

Comment: considering how this things are usually put together, I honestly think that if there are 2 memory module of ~32Gb, at least 1 of those is fried and gone, but it was really the first formatting, never seen something like that.

Comment: Are there any messages in `dmesg` or syslog that indicate that the drive might be malfunctioning?

Comment: @DarthAndroid nope, nothing at all under Windows too

Answer (score 0):

Check what type of partition table you have on the V---tim device,
then Remove ALL partitions and partition table on it.
Recreate the partition table with e.g. gparted, make sure it is GPT type.

I know there is a 32GB limit in some situation - but cannot pinpoint it, sorry.

Comment: I tried crossing different filesystems, utilities and partition tables ( MBR and GPT ), the outcome is basically the same in any case.